# Why does this string comparison code return 1 in php?

Tags: php

I'm confused as to why this returns 1 (true) when both the string have an equal length or the same number of letters.

```
echo 'shaun' < 'yoshi';
```

returns 1 but I don't understand how?

Answer (score 2):

An example might make things more clear:

https://3v4l.org/RWaas

When you do

```
$string1 < $string2
```

you are essentially comparing the first letter of both strings, so your comparison turns into:

```
ord('s') < ord('y')
```

which becomes

```
115 < 121
```

which is

```
true
```

which, when used `echo` on it is

```
1
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php - Interprets the binary value of the first byte of string as an unsigned integer between 0 and 255.